# Same variable for different datatypes?

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I have to call one simple functions with different datatypes in c++. eg,

```
void Test(enum value)
{
      int x;
      float y; // etc
      if(value == INT)
      {
         // do some operation on x

      }
      else if(value == float)
      {
         // do SAME operation on y
      }
      else if(value == short)
      {
         // AGAIN SAME operation on short variable
      }
      .
      .
      .
}
```

Thus I want to eliminate the repetitive code  for different datatypes ...
So , I tried to use macro ,depending on values of enum, to define same variable for different datatypes .. but then not able to differentiate between the MACROS

e.g.

```
void Test(enum value)
{
      #if INT 
       typedef int datatype;
      #elif FLOAT 
       typedef float datatype;
      .
      .
      .
      #endif

      datatype x;

      // Do operation on same variable

}
```

But now every time the first condition #if INT is getting true.
I tried to set different values of macro to differentiate but not working :(

Can anyone help me achieve the above thing.

Comment: do you need `#ifdef`?

Comment: You cannot name your function as main.

Comment: Can you be more specific: do you want to switch by enum value or do you want to write same code for different arg types?

Comment: exactly what repititive code are we talking about here (in order to better understand your problem) ?

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

//type generic method definition using templates
template <typename T> 
void display(T arr[], int size) {
    cout << "inside display " << endl;
    for (int i= 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main() {

    int a[10];
    string s[10];
    double d[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
        d[i] = i + 0.1;
        stringstream std;
        std <<  "string - "<< i;
        s[i] = std.str();
    }
    display(a, 10); //calling for integer array
    display(s, 10); // calling for string array
    display(d, 10); // calling for double array
    return 0;
}
```

If you really want your function to be generic, template is the way to go. Above is the way to do and call the method from main method. This might be of some help for you to reuse a function for different types. Pick up any tutorial or C++ books for complete understanding on templates and get a grip of the full concepts. Cheers.

Comment: you could well take `template<typename T, int N> void display (std::array<T, N>)` instead; Explicit size as second parameter makes code error-prone and is a C-era relict.

Answer (score 3):

You can use templates to achieve you purpose.

Simply write a template function which take the value in the function argument which is of generic type and put the operational logic inside it. Now call the function with different data types.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use function overloading:

```
void foo(int arg) { /* ... */ }
void foo(long arg) { /* ... */ }
void foo(float arg) { /* ... */ }
```

Supposing you want do the same operation with integer and long types you can eliminate the code repetition in this way:

```
void foo(long arg) { /* ... */ }
void foo(int arg) { foo((long) arg); }
```